# Facing issue while installing Keystone@next 4.0 beta

Tags: node.js, content-management-system, keystonejs

I am having issue while installing **Keystone@next** ( beta version).I am using below command.

i did npm init in **D:/keystone** drive

```
npm install --save keystone@next
```

I am just getting node modules using the installation steps provided on keystone github dir, and missing the core files to run keystone project.

GitHub : https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone#keystone-40-beta-released

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [generator-keystone](https://github.com/keystonejs/generator-keystone). You need to install [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) before using `generator-keystone`. I used Yeoman generator a few months ago and it installed the beta version of KeystoneJS for me at that time:

```
$ cat Documents/brand-keystonejs/package.json 
{
  "name": "studio",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "2.1.4",
    "cloudinary": "1.7.0",
    "connect-mongo": "^2.0.0",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "express-handlebars": "3.0.0",
    "handlebars": "4.0.6",
    "keystone": "4.0.0-beta.5",
    "lodash": "^4.13.1",
    "moment": "2.17.1",
    "node-sass": "4.5.0",
    "node-sass-middleware": "0.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "3.15.0",
    "eslint-config-keystone": "3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "node keystone.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: Keystonejs latest documents is not updated yet. Below are the detail steps to configure any version of keystonejs as of 4.0 Release.

`npm init`

`npm install -g generator-keystone`

`yo keystone`

to change keystone version modify package.json file in your root dir.